# How to read a slack user ID from response and get the username?

Tags: python, slack

Code:

```
@slackbot.command('hi')
def idk():


    user =  slackbot.slack_client.api_call(
    "users.info",
     user=command.user,

    )
    print(user)
```

When the user types of command in slack as "!hi", that users information is taken into the command.
This is what I have so far, but how do I now extract purely the users first name?
`print(user)` at the moment prints everything I need to see, including the `'first_name:"name"`, but how do I now single this out?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`api_call` returns a dictionary of the user including many variables, which you are setting to `user`.  The general version to get one value is `dictionary[<key>]`, or in your case `user["first_name"]`.

Comment: I did this, but it came up with: KeyError:'first_name'

Comment: Where did you try it? I'm thinking it should work inside the print statement.

Comment: I tried print(user['first_name']) at the end of the function

Comment: I realized I had to write print(user["user"]["first_name"]), to access that dictionary initially. Thank you!

Comment: Well glad you got the answer, i'll look up some better documentation and update a code example when I get home.